# How to add/insert data using EF core code first for reference values?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Let's say we have a table which stores references/foreign keys to several tables. We are to insert record in such table using EF Core code first approach.

Here is what I have:

```
_context.AuditLog.Add(new AuditLog
            {
                UserId = _context.User.Single(u => u.name == name).UserId,
                ApplicationActionId = _context.ApplicationAction.Single(a=>a.Name == applicationname).ApplicationActionId,
                AddressID = _context.Address.Single(t=>t.addressName == addressName).addressId
            });
```

Is it the correct way?

I question this, because for each foreign key, we have to perform search to get it's ID value. My models do have relationships defined so can we use navigational properties?

I tried searching up, but couldn't get any examples around it. All the examples are very basic, like storing first name, last name etc.

Comment: Well, show classes with navigation properties. Instead of three queries we can compose one.

Comment: it's an extract from the actual code, but let's assume that AuditLog is a table and that stores foreign keys of userid, application id and address id.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefits from `AuditLog` navigation properties, but you can sppedup generating inserted record.

```cs
var dataQuery = 
    from u in context.User
    where u.name == name
    from a in _context.ApplicationAction
    where a.Name == applicationname
    from t in _context.Address
    where t.addressName == addressName
    select new AuditLog
    {
        UserId = u.UserId,
        ApplicationActionId = a.ApplicationActionId,
        AddressID = t.AddressId
    };

var record = dataQuery.First();

context.AuditLog.Add(record);
```

This query has sevral performance fixes:

1. One query instead of three
2. Not retriveing whole objects for just ID properties

Comment: Looks promising, can you pls provide any reference for this? as I am wondering what the dataQuery is and if we use "from u in context.User where u.name == name" then won't it be the same as "_context.User.Single(u => u.name == name).UserId"?

Comment: `Single` throws exception if there are no records or two or more records. Don't think you need that for auditing.

Comment: You can replace `First()` from my answer with `Single()` and it will do the same check as in your question.